# Trying to do a simple "hello world" program in DCPU-16

Tags: assembly, dcpu-16

I'm studying the DCPU-16's asm, and I started with a simple hello world program. Here it is:

```
hwn i
set j, 0

jsr get_display

:init_display
set a, 0
set b, 0x8000
hwi [display_adress]
set i, 0


:write_string
 set a, [message + j]
 ife a, 0
    set pc, end
 jsr write_char
 set pc, write_string

:write_char
 bor a, 0xA000
 set [0x8000 + j], a
 add j, 1
 set pc, pop

:get_display
hwq [display_adress]
add [display_adress], 1
ifn a, 0xf615
    set pc, get_display
set pc, pop

:get_keyboard
hwq [keyboard_adress]
add [keyboard_adress], 1
ifn a, 0x7406
    set pc, get_keyboard 
set pc, pop

:get_clock
hwq [clock_adress]
add [clock_adress], 1
ifn a, 0xb402
    set pc, get_clock
set pc, pop

:get_sped
hwq [sped_adress]
add [sped_adress], 1
ifn a, 0xbf3c
    set pc, get_sped
set pc, pop

:display_adress dat 0x0000
:keyboard_adress dat 0x0000
:clock_adress dat 0x0000
:sped_adress dat 0x0000

:message dat "Hello World!", 0

:end
```

The program find the display, register the video RAM and copy the characters to the video RAM memory, but nothing happens with the screen! Could someone help me?

Comment: It seems to work when tested on the emulator at http://aws.johnmccann.me/ - how are you running it?

Comment: Weird. It seems not work in 0x10co.de . But thank you for help!